# Как через bash получить первый символ после подстроки?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Известно что в файле есть некоторая подстрока.
Собственно как получить первый символ после этой подстроки?

Comment: `rest=${line#*подстрока}; echo ${rest%${rest#?}}`

Comment: `grep 'подстрока' /file | grep -o '^.'`, способов на самом деле достаточно много

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указали коллеги, вариантов много.  Вот через сочетание *grep*
и *sed* (подстрока `BAR`):

```sh
$ grep -e 'BAR' ./file.txt | sed -e 's/.*BAR\(.\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: `sed -n -e '/BAR/s/.../p'  ./file.txt` grep можно исключить по идее вот так.А в коментариях к вопросу, я видимо не так его понял)